# How to run a function based on the completion of an AJAX call within an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I've got a page that contains an iframe. Both the page and iframe reside on the same domain.

Within the iframe there is an AJAX call being made for some data that populates some input fields within the iframe.

I need to extract a variable value called useableData from the iframe back to the parent page. This variable value is one that gets created after the AJAX call.

I find myself stuck at this point. I've tried putting an onload function call against the iframe and my variable comes back as undefined.

**Attempt #1**

```
$(window).load(function () {
   var fName = $("#one-time-form")[0].contentWindow.useableData;
   console.log(fName);
});
```

Realizing that didn't work I put an onload directly on the iframe element and then re-worked the function

**Attempt #2**

```
<iframe id="one-time-form" onload="testFunction();"></iframe>

function testFunction {
    var fName = $("#one-time-form")[0].contentWindow.useableData;
    console.log(fName);   
 }
```

Still nothing they both return an undefined variable value.

Then I came across the `.ajaxStop` function in jQuery and gave it a try.

**Attempt #3**

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    var fName = $("#one-time-form")[0].contentWindow.useableData;
    console.log(fName);
});
```

This also returned an undefined value, presumably because it's being called in the parent page where no Ajax calls originated to begin with.

Lastly, I attempted a local storage attempt using the HTML API. I defined the variable within the iframe inside my AJAX success function.

**Setting local storage in iframe**

```
localStorage.setItem('fName', useableData);
```

Then back in the parent page within an onload function call I have this

**Retrieve locale storage in parent page**

```
const sessData = localStorage.getItem('fName'); 
console.log ("session var called sessData is: " + sessData);
```

But, yet again, I get an undefined variable, presumably because the AJAX call isn't finished yet.

Comment: If you have control of the code in both the iframe and parent window, I'd suggest using [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan , I'd attempted that as well but couldn't get past my console errors in my original attempt. Is that something you could provide a skeleton example of?

Comment: Sure, I just added an example for you in an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control of the code in both the iframe and parent window, I'd suggest using [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

```
// in the iframe:
$(window).load(function () {
  let message = { useableData: $("#one-time-form")[0].contentWindow.useableData }
  window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');
});

// in the parent:
window.addEventListener("message", e => {
  let useableData = e.data.useableData;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a million for this, closest and most helpful answer I've gotten as I work through this. During my implementation I'm getting a console error though. Posting it just in a new comment

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window'

Comment: Which browser are you using? Also, try setting the actual domain of the parent window in the second argument instead of `'*'` - I only used that as a placeholder.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I got it, I'd fat fingered a bracket. All good and I'm logging my value properly back to my parent page. I can't thank you enough for this solution. So much cleaner than the others I'd attempted!

Answer (score 0):

In general, in order to communicate with an iframe, it's (usually) necessary to use `postMessage` to send and recieve data, a simple example that you can adopt:

```
<iframe id=oy src="something"></iframe>
```

and then the source for "something" url..

```
<script>
onmessage = e => {
    e.source.postMessage("hi bacK!", "*")
}
</script>
```

now back in the main file... (continued)

```
<script>
oy.postMessage("hi there, what's going on?")
oy.onmessage = e => console.log(e)
</script>
```